# Downloading German pronunciation

Tags: pronunciation, resource, dictionary

Is there a website that has audio for words and will allow me to download the audio so I can use it with my Anki deck so I can learn better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a few, but I think the most comprehensive resource for that purpose would be https://www.duden.de. Search for a word, check the "Aussprache" section, right-click on the icon and select "Save link as"/"save target as" (depending on your browser), which allows you to save it as an .mp3 file. E.g.: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Haus. https://de.wiktionary.org/ also has some spoken pronounciations, of varying quality, that are easy to download.

(There are also many sites out there that provide computer-generated pronounciations, but I've always considered that nonsensical: If the pronounciation is simple, you don't need it, and if it is difficult, it will often be incorrect. The *Duden* samples are by professional speakers.)

Since, according to a recent article by Stefan Kleiner in the IDS Jahrbuch 2018,  *Duden* seems to be planning to provide spoken pronounciations for all of its entries on duden.de, this might become an even more useful resource going forward.

Comment: i don't know what icon you're talking about!

Comment: @hiwa-gg The loudspeaker icon in the Aussprache section at https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Haus. (It's not available in every entry since not all of them do have recordings available.)

Comment: ok thanks, but i found downloading from forvo much easier, anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The site [forvo.com](https://forvo.com) has people record words and also contains a lot of names, what you would otherwise not have in a traditional translator.